# How to open specific link in android webview app?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, ads

I have integrated a website in an android app using WebView.

```
webtcet.loadUrl("http://www.myaddaa.in/");
 webtcet.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());

private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
}
```

But when i try to open ads link in android app(running in my phone it has google play services) it shows could not be loaded.

[image: Webview contain vodafone ads]
[image: after clicking on download icon]

So how would i open the link directly to playstore and not in webview if it is ads?
Thank in advance

Comment: this is 404 not found error ...means that url is not exist ..please do some resarch before posting

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @Tufan but how can i open the link through webview to playstore. I mean how it is done? can u help me with code ...:)

Comment: The problem is that your WebView is overriding the loading process and loading it into the WebView. Check if the url starts with "market" and if it does don't load it into your WebView and let Android handle it (check your return value for that).

Answer (score 0):

1. I don'k think it's a good idea to open market directly inside the webview. The best way is to pass the intent to play store like this

   ```
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+YOU_APP_ID)));
   ```
2. If you really need this behaviour for some reason, you have to intercept all  `market://` links and load them as usual browser links

   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   ```
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
             [parse the link to get app id from url]
             webview.loadUrl(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[YOU_APP_ID]);
           }
        });
   ```

Comment: i dont want to open market link in webview. i want to open those links accordingly to playstore or browser .but the problem is its trying to load all link in webview. i hope u got the question.

Answer (score 0):

so just intercept this links inside your shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
            try {
               startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // open link in browser as described above
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```